# SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 99 Current browser version is 105

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, robotframework

I am currently new to robot framework. currently using latest version of chrome and ChromeDriver which is 105 but when i try to run the test it gives the message "SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 99" I have tried uninstalling everything and reinstalling it again but nothing works can anyone help me with this. Thank you!

Screenshots below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fRtjl.png)
SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 99
Current browser version is 105.0.5195.127 with binary path C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fRtjl.png)

Comment: The message seems pretty clear: you have a version mismatch between chrome and chromedriver. Have you tried installing the correct version of chromedriver, and have you verified that the versions are the same? You can only get this error if you have the wrong version of chromedriver for the version of chrome you are running.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome driver has [a page](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads/version-selection) on how to identify the exact version that you need, but it's a pain, especially if you regularly update chrome, or want to make it part of a build process.

Not sure about robot framework, but [chromedriver-autoinstaller](https://github.com/yeongbin-jo/python-chromedriver-autoinstaller) sure helped me out when building a pipeline to get a selenium/chrome project going, as it will detect the version of chrome installed and install the correct driver version automatically.